# ion-autocomplete cancel-label with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the function `lang(keyval)` in my `rootScope` to get the right language for a given Keyvalue.

Normally i use `ng-bind` to bind the value to a `span` or `div` which is working fine.

Now i want to use it as `cancel-label` [see docs](https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#cancel-button-label) for the `ion-autocomplete` just like `cancel-label="lang('CANCEL')"` but the function is not resolved

Comment: The issue https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete/issues/76 is now fixed. Please try it with the master. Thanks.

Comment: It's working, nice thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `cancel-label` is not a two way binded value so currently you cannot do this. I just created an issue in which I will solve this such that you can set it as a scope/controller variable.

https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete/issues/76

Thanks and regards,

Guy